# How to show the string value of a non id field for a model in an ember.js route?

Tags: ember.js

I have a custom field that allows you to filter down a list of models (on some ArrayController lets say)

```
  PersonApp.SearchField = Ember.TextField.extend({
      keyUp: function(e) {
          var search = this.get('value');
          model = PersonApp.Page.create({term: search});
          this.get('controller.target').transitionTo('person.search', model);       
      }
  });
```

Here is the very simple model I'm using for both pagination and filtering/search

```
  PersonApp.Page = Ember.Object.extend({                                            
      term: ''
  });
```

I added a simple route that works with the model above

```
  PersonApp.Router.map(function(match) {
      this.resource("person", { path: "/" }, function() {
          this.route("page", { path: "/page/:page_id" });
          this.route("search", { path: "/search/:page_term" });                     
      });
  });
```

And finally here is my route setupController method

```
 PersonApp.PersonSearchRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
     setupController: function(controller, model) {
         this.controllerFor('person').set('filterBy', model.get('term'));
     }
 });
```

The filter does work (meaning it does modify the ArrayController using the filterBy in my setupController above).

But in the URL I see the following

```
http://www.google.com/#/search/<PersonApp.Page:ember517>
```

Instead of

```
http://www.google.com/#/search/foo
```

Any way I can modify the model/route/setupController to show the text instead?

Also- should something like this just be a simple "event" on the index / main route instead of a custom route as I have it above? If so can I still modify the url (I assume not -so that's why I have it as a route for now)

Comment: I think `set("filterBy", model.get("term"))` returns a Person Page whose `term` matches that provided in the route. Try just `set(model.get("term"))`.

Comment: In setupController or ?

Comment: Yes, in setupController. This is a guess, not an answer.

Comment: `this.controllerFor('person').set(model.get('term'));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `serialize` hook in the `PersonSearchRoute`.  According to the [`serialize` docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_serialize), `serialize` is:

> A hook you can implement to convert the route's model into parameters for the URL.

For your example:

```
PersonApp.PersonSearchRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this.controllerFor('person').set('filterBy', model.get('term'));
  },
  model: function(params) {
    return PersonApp.Page.create({term: params.page_term});
  },
  serialize: function(model) {
    return { page_term: model.term };
  }
});
```

[JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/ixupad/202/edit)

This will show the correct URL: `#/search/foo` but if you navigate to that URL directly, or refresh the page at that URL you will need to use the `model` hook to find and return a model using the provided dynamic parameter.  The value returned from the `model` hook is the `model` parameter passed into `setupController` when navigating directly to a URL, but if a `transitionTo` or a `{{#linkTo}}` is used the object passed with those calls is passed directly to `setupController`.