# No 'addArrayObserver' or 'removeArrayObserver'

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am modelling an administrative interface that helps manage database tables. There are two models: [DbxTables, DbxColumns]. I want to allow the user to choose a table using Boostrap's tab-menu and then be able to see the columns in that table. This mostly works. For instance, if I type `http://my.domain.com/index.html#/performance` where `performance` is the name of the *table* I get the following:

[image: performance table]

If I decide to go to another table by manipulating the URL -- for instance `http://my.domain.com/index.html#/food`-- then it will successfully switch to the food columns in the right-hand pane. The problems come in when I use my {{linkTo}} links in the left-hand tab menu. One of two things happens:

1. If the {{linkTo}} looks like `{{linkTo 'columns' this}}` then it makes the URL parameter something like `<App.DbxTable:ember371:performance>` rather than just `performance`
2. If the {{linkTo}} looks like `{{linkTo 'columns' this.id}}` then it sets the ULR parameter correctly (or at least so it appears to in the URL window) but the if I click on "meal" in the left-hand tab menu I get the following error: *Object meal has no method 'addArrayObserver'*. If I click on something else it follows that error message with "*Object meal has no method 'removeArrayObserver'* ".

In both of the above cases, after receiving an error, the column names on the right hand side do not update. The first style of {{linkTo}} is what the [screencast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ga99hMi7wfY) from Tom Dale seemed to suggest was the right syntax. However, seeing that the links were off I came up with the `this.id` approach. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

For some additional code context (router.js):

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('about');
    this.resource('dbx', function() {
        this.resource('columns', { path: ':dbx_table'});
    });
    this.resource('oauth');
    this.resource('postTypeMappings');
});

App.DbxRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return App.DbxTable.find();
    }
});
App.ColumnsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(table) {
        return App.DbxColumn.find(table);
    }
});
```

Model: dbx_table.js

```
App.DbxTable = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr("string"),
    desc: DS.attr("string"),
    db_column: DS.attr("string"),
    columns: DS.attr("raw")
});
```

Model: dbx_column.js

```
App.DbxColumn = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr("string"),
    dbType: DS.attr("string"),
    insight: DS.attr("string"),
    enum: DS.attr("string"),
    staticUom: DS.attr("string"),
    uomContext: DS.attr("string"),
    jsonStruct: DS.attr("string"),
    desc: DS.attr("string")
});
```

Model: store.js

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 12,
    adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.reopen({
        namespace: 'api/lifegadget'
    })
});

DS.RESTAdapter.registerTransform('raw', {
    deserialize: function(serialized) {
        return serialized;
    },  
    serialize: function(deserialized) {
        return deserialized;
    }
});
```

UPDATE (adding handlebars):

In order to provide some more detail. Here are the handlebars templates:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Ember Starter Kit</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <a class="brand" href="#">Admin</a>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li>{{#linkTo "dbx"}}DBX{{/linkTo}}</li>
            <li>{{#linkTo "postTypeMappings"}}Post Mappings{{/linkTo}}</li>
            <li>{{#linkTo "oauth"}}OAuth{{/linkTo}}</li>
            <li>{{#linkTo "about"}}About{{/linkTo}}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="outlet-target">
    {{outlet}}
    </div>
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="about">
  <div class='about'>
      Admin Screen
  </div>
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="dbx">
  <div class='dbx'>
  <div id="dbx-table-pane" class="tabbable tabs-left">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        {{#each model}}
            <li>
                {{#linkTo "columns" this}}{{db_column}}{{/linkTo}}
            </li>
        {{/each}}
        <li id="add-table">
            <a href="#section-add-table" data-toggle="tab"><em>Add DBX Table</em></a>
        </li>       
    </ul>
    <div id="dbx-main" class="tab-content">
    {{outlet}}
    </div
  </div>

  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="columns">
      The columns are:
      <ul>
        {{#each model}}
        <li>{{name}}</li>
        {{/each}}
      </ul>
  </script> 

  <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/handlebars-1.0.0-rc.3.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ember-1.0.0-rc.2.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ember-data-12.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/router.js"></script>
  <script src="js/models/store.js"></script>
  <script src="js/models/dbx_table.js"></script>
  <script src="js/models/dbx_column.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE 2:

I've now added a short video that demonstrates the problem: https://vimeo.com/63388787

Comment: what does the handlebars code look like?

Comment: I've added the handlebars code above

Answer (score 1):

This looks similar to this question: [How to show the string value of a non id field for a model in an ember.js route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375127/how-to-show-the-string-value-of-a-non-id-field-for-a-model-in-an-ember-js-route)

I think you will need to use the [`serialize` hook](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_serialize) in your `ColumnsRoute` to define how the model is turned into the URL dynamic segment.

```
App.ColumnsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(table) {
        return App.DbxColumn.find(table);
    },
    //dbx_table matches the dynamic route name in your router, and I am assuming
    // you want to use the DbxColumn.name as the URL parameter
    serialize: function(model) {
      return {dbx_table: model.get('name')}; 
    }
});
```

The `model` hook handles turning a URL into a model object when the URL is directly navigated to, and the `serialize` hook is used to construct the URL when a route is transitioned to using an already existing object, such as when `transitionTo` or a `{{#linkTo}}` is used.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still stuck but I think this is a step in the right direction. I added the serialize method to the ColumnsRoute but set it to the "id" property rather than the "name". This visually appears to point it to the right URL (aka, #/dbx/food, #dbx/performance, etc.) but I immediately get a *Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'addArrayObserver'* If I instead manually type in the URL then it works without issue.

Comment: Bizarrely I have now noticed that if I choose the menu item "food_summary" I get this error: *Uncaught Error: assertion failed: an Ember.CollectionView's content must implement Ember.Array. You passed <App.DbxTable:ember345:food_summary>*. If I choose anything else I get the Uncaught TypeError: *Object [object Object] has no method 'removeArrayObserver'* error. Weird.

Comment: I have added a very short video that demonstrates the problem. Note the "assertion failed" error can not be reproduced reliably. It seems to be just the "type error" that I'm contending with now: https://vimeo.com/63388787

Comment: @ken in your `columns` template does changing `{{#each model}}` to `{{#each content}}` do anything?

Comment: I've now tried `content`, `model`, and `controller` and they all appear to result in the same thing.

Comment: BTW, I mentioned the "Assertion Failed" message ... I CAN now reproduce reliably. If I start from the root index.html page then navigate to the "DBX" tab (which successfully calls the list of tables) and then choose one of the tables -- let's say *general_exercise*-- then I get the following error `Uncaught Error: assertion failed: an Ember.CollectionView's content must implement Ember.Array. You passed <App.DbxTable:ember434:general_exercise>`. All subsequent clicks on table names give me the "TypeError" already described.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that through all of these variations that do NOT work when I click through them ... if I reload the page with the URL that has been generated ... it works fine. I'm really stuck but it must have something to do with the way JS is passing information during the `{{linkTo}}` call that is different from what the router passes when I just load up a URL instead. Unfortunately I'm too much of a newbie to explore it much further than that.

Comment: @ken I put together a JSBin from your post using the fixture adpater.  Can you populate it with enough fake data and any other changes you've made so it shows your issue?  http://jsbin.com/uwafob/1/edit

Comment: I have the very same problem here. I manage to write a working descrialize method, when I have to find some id in a model. ie have serialize() return {address_id: 5}. As soon I try something analogously with a dynamic route (i.e. return {search: "foo=bar"}) it fails with "has no method 'addArrayObserver'", even though calling the URL directly /x/foo=bar works. It is quite unclear what the serialize method is supposed to return. my related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16506634/ember-route-with-dynamic-filter-search-criterias