# Ember route with dynamic filter / search criterias

Tags: ember.js

With the following problem I got stuck now for days. My use case is that I have a database with millions of addresses. From an web-application I would like to search them, display a list of resuls and later display information about a single address. One important goal is, to represent the search criteria as part of the URL. That way users can go back to previous searches or even construct the search by manipulating the URL. So I would like to have a URL like this:

```
http://localhost/#/searchresults?lastname=king&firstname=stephen&city=somecity
```

I don't manage to setup the router to process these kind of URLs. All a tried ended in a dead end. How to make ember go into the /searchresults route and how to have it forward those filter criterias using the RESTAdapter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the answer from intuitivepixel I came up with the following solution.

I construct the following URL:
    http://somedomain.com/#/searchresults/?lastname=king&firstname=stephen&city=somecity

The way how this URL is contructed is not described here. In my case I use a my own view with a form and some event handlers.

The code that I got working looks like this:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource("searchresults", { path: '/searchresults/:dynamic' });
});

App.SearchresultsRoute = Ember.Route.extend((function() {
    var deserializeQueryString = function (queryString) {
        if(queryString.charAt(0) === "?")
            queryString = queryString.substr(1);

        var vars = queryString.split('&'),
            i = 0, length = vars.length,
            outputObj = {};

        for (; i < length; i++) {
            var pair = vars[i].split('=');
            outputObj[decodeURIComponent(pair[0])] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
        }
        return outputObj;
    };

    return {
          model: function(param) {
            var paramObj = deserializeQueryString(param.dynamic);
            return App.Searchresult.find(paramObj);
          }
        };
    })()
);

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 12,
    adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create({
        namespace: 'api'
    })
});

App.Searchresult = DS.Model.extend({
    lastname: DS.attr('string'),
    firstname: DS.attr('string'),
    street: DS.attr('string'),
    hno: DS.attr('string'),
    zip: DS.attr('string'),
    city: DS.attr('string'),
    country: DS.attr('string'),
    birthdate: DS.attr('string')
});
```

This generates an HTTP GET request to my REST API:

```
http://somedomain.com/api/searchresults?lastname=king&firstname=stephen&city=somecity
```

My REST API responds with:

```
{"searchresults":
    [{"id":"2367507","lastname":"King","firstname":"Stephen","street":"Mainstreet.","hno":"21" ...},
     {"id":"3222409","lastname":"King","firstname":"Stephen","street":"Broadway","hno":"35" ...}
    ]}
```

And this then gets visualized with this template:

```
<h2>Searchresults</h2>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Street / Hno</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Birthyear</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {{#each item in controller}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{item.firstname}} {{item.lastname}}</td>
            <td>{{item.street}} {{item.hno}}</td>
            <td>{{item.zip}} {{item.city}}</td>
            <td>{{item.birthdate}}</td>
        </tr>   
    {{/each}}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If somebody finds a more elegant way, that does not require to use a custom deserializer, I will be glad to update the solution. The answer provided by (the other) Daniel that suggests http://somedomain.com/#/searchresults/king/stephen/somecity is not parctial for my case, since in the solution that I need, I have more than 10 different search criterias / filters. Users usually only choose to fill a few of them.

This examples base on ember-data revision: 12 and Ember 1.0.0-RC.3

Answer (score 3):

To take advantage of ember data you could do it this way. 
Assuming you have a model like this:

```
App.SearchResult = DS.Model.extend({
  firstName: DS.attr('string'),
  lastName: DS.attr('string'),
  city: DS.attr('string')
});
```

and then you do in your Route's model hook you do this:

```
App.SearchResultsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params){
    return App.SearchResult.find({firstName:params.firstName,lastName:params.lastName,city:params.city})
  }
});
```

this way the RESTAdapter will automatically issue a request like your example:

```
http://localhost/#/searchresults?firstname=xxx&lastname=xxx&city=xxx
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I tried this, however I get this error: "Uncaught Error: No route matched the URL '/searchresults?name=anna'". My App.Router.map contains "his.resource('searchresults');"

Comment: I thought you hade already the dynamic segment: `this.resource('searchresults', { path: '/searchresults/:dynamic' });`

Comment: Awesome. That way I will get it to work. There will be two differences: The URL is now ...ts/?firstname=x... with dash before "?". 2. The params passed to model() in SearchResultsRoute are not structured as seen in your example. Instead I get {dynamic: "?name=anna"}. So additionally I will have to deserialize the query string. I can easily deal with that.

Comment: Cool, I also thought that you would have to hook in to the serialize/deserialize method of the Route, I'm glad It did work out :)

Answer (score 0):

I've got URL that contains information about news page number and depending on this it sends and ajax call. My router looks like:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('news', { path: '/n/:id' });
});
```

But you could also do it like:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
        this.resource('searchresults', { path: '/searchresults/:lastname/:firstname/:city' });
    });
```

And your URL would look like this:

```
http://localhost/#/searchresults/king/stephen/somecity
```

Then you just specify:

```
App.SearchresultsRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        var lastname = params.lastname;
            var firstname = params.firstname;
            var city = params.city;
            someFunction(lastname, firstname, city);
    }
});
```

I hope my answer helped you. Have a nice day!

Comment: This might work. However, my actual model and my search form is quite a bit more complex. A user can choose from 10+ fields (firstname, name, street, housenumber, birthdate, ...). In order to search, a user usually only provides content for a few of those fields. If I would construct URLs like this, they would always have to contain explicitly all the criterias, even though most of those fields are empty: i.e. http://localhost/#/searchresults/king/stephen////////somecity. I don't like, the URL does not 'show' what a position stands for. Ie it is not visible, that position 3 stands for street.